# Iterate through worksheets adding data to each iteration

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image: Input File]
[image: Output FIle]

I have an excel file in which all data is listed in rows(first Image), I need to take this data and list it in column A of individual worksheets in a newly created workbook(Needs to look like the 2nd image). I am having issues getting the proper 'for' loop, so the data is written each separate worksheet. My code now writes that data all on the same worksheet.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import time

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('IP-Results.xlsx') #load input file
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('IP-Results-32708') #get sheet from input file

wbOutput = openpyxl.Workbook() #open a new workbook
wbOutput.remove_sheet(wbOutput.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')) #remove initial worksheet named 'sheet'

for cell in sheet['A']: #iterate through firewall names in column A and make those the title of the sheets in new workbook
    value = cell.value
    wbOutput.create_sheet(title=cell.value)

inputwb = wb
inputsheet = inputwb.active
outputwb = wbOutput
outputsheet = outputwb.active
maxRow = inputsheet.max_row
maxCol = inputsheet.max_column

for i in range(1, max(maxRow, maxCol) +1):
    for j in range(1, min(maxRow, maxCol) + 1):
        for sheet in outputwb.get_sheet_names():
            outputsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value  = inputsheet.cell(row=j, column=i).value
            outputsheet.cell(row=j, column=i).value  = inputsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value

wbOutput.save("Decom-" + time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")+ ".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'outputsheet' is assigned to refer to the first (the default) sheet in wbOutput:

```
outputwb = wbOutput
outputsheet = outputwb.active
```

Then the main loop writes to outputsheet which always refers to the same original worksheet, causing all your data to appear on the same sheet:

```
for i in range(1, max(maxRow, maxCol) +1):
    for j in range(1, min(maxRow, maxCol) + 1):
        for sheet in outputwb.get_sheet_names():
            **outputsheet**.cell(row=i, column=j).value  = inputsheet.cell(row=j, column=i).value
            **outputsheet**.cell(row=j, column=i).value  = inputsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value
```

The easiest solution would be dropping the third inner loop and using get_sheet_by_name:

```
for i in range(1, max(maxRow, maxCol) +1):
        sheet_name = inputsheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        a_sheet = outputwb .get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        for j in range(1, min(maxRow, maxCol) + 1):
            a_sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value  = inputsheet.cell(row=j, column=i).value
```

I can't test the code at the moment but the general idea should work.

**edit**

Although it might be worth redesigning to something like this pseudo code:

```
for each inputwb_row in inputworkbook:
    new_sheet = create a new_sheet in outputworkbook
    set new_sheet.title = inputworkbook.cell[row,1].value
    for each column in inputwb_row:
        new_sheet.cell[column, 1].value =  inputworkbook.cell[inputwb_row ,column].value
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Appreciate you help!